# How to compute second-order derivative with respect to a vector in python (pytorch?)

Tags: python, numpy, vector, pytorch, derivative

I am trying to write up a code that performs metropolized iid sampling, and I am having troubles computing the second-order derivative of a function with respect to a numpy `ndarray`. The code I wrote so far are shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton

w = np.array([4,5,3,6,2])
y = np.array([1,0,0,1,1])
lamb = np.array([0.001, 0.0045, 0.0072,0.0083, 0.0069)]
tau = np.array([0.0002, 0.00045, 0.000378, 0.00467, 0.00235])              

# define function f       
def f(gamma):
    
    return (-1) * (np.dot(y, np.dot(w, gamma)) - np.sum(np.log(np.exp(np.dot(w,gamma)) + 1)) - np.sum((np.subtract(gamma,lamb)) * (np.subtract(gamma,lamb)) / (2*tau*tau)))

# mode for the metropolized iid sampler
gamma_hat = newton(f, gamma, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=50, fprime2=None)

# not sure how to calculate the variance for the same sampler
```

What I want to do:

To calculate the variance for the sampler, I want to take the second-order derivative of the function `f` with respect to the vector variable `gamma`, and then compute the value of the second derivative after substituting `gamma = gamma_hat`.

Can I do this in python? If needed, I am willing to use the `pytorch` for calculating the value of the second order derivative.

Thank you,

Comment: Your code doesn't run without errors (and after fixing the first error, I get a second one). Please fix it.

Comment: Also, please specify what you mean by 2nd derivative for vectors; do you mean the [laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) or the [second-order partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Higher_order_partial_derivatives)?